# Difference between these two attr_reader?

Tags: ruby

```
class CustomerClass < ActiveRecord
   class << self
     attr_reader :lov
   end
   attr_reader :lov1
end
```

What is the diffrence between attr_reader lov and lov1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `:lov` will be a class-level accessor, while `:lov1` is instance-level.

So, you can only access `lov1` from an **instance**:

```
customer = CustomerClass.new
lov1 = customer.lov1
```

While `CustomerClass.lov1` wouldn't work, but `CustomerClass.lov` would.

Comment: Can you please explain it with proper example ?